# Is there a way to change all stdout data before it fired in the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, stdout

I need to manipulate all the data that is sent to the stdout .
as sdtout is a stream i try to do

```js
process.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
  //change chunk and return it
});
```

but that didn't do anything.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/intercept-stdout

You can hook into stdout using this module:

```
var intercept = require("intercept-stdout");

var unhook_intercept = intercept(function(txt) {
    return txt.replace( /this/i , 'that' );
});

console.log("This text is being modified");

// Stop intercepting stdout
unhook_intercept();

console.log("This text is _not_ being modified");
```